# How do you call `bpy.ops.clip.rebuild_proxy()` in the python api without getting a context is incorrect error

Tags: python

I am trying to get proxy timecodes rendered for the blender nle via the python API. However once I call `bpy.ops.clip.rebuild_proxy()` or `bpy.ops.sequencer.rebuild_proxy()` instantly get the error `RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.clip.rebuild_proxy.poll() failed, context is incorrect`
I have tried tracking down the function in C but I cannot find anything that helps point towards the root cause, or how to properly call `rebuild_proxy()`

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add

Answer (score 1):

So it sounds like the problem is that the wrong part of the interface ('Area') is active at the moment you're calling ops.clip.rebuild_proxy() or sequencer.rebuild_proxy().

I'm working on an add-on that will allow me to add a movie strip, draw waveforms, and start a 50% proxy build all with a single action. I found that I had to iterate through the areas and override the context to rebuild proxy for a specific clip. Here's what worked for me:

```
ctx = bpy.context.copy()
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'CLIP_EDITOR':
        ctx['area'] = area
        bpy.ops.clip.rebuild_proxy()
```

Comment: Did you not have to pass the ctx to the operator? bpy.ops.clip.rebuild_proxy(ctx)

Comment: No according to docs: https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.sequencer.html#bpy.ops.sequencer.rebuild_proxy

Comment: The docs only document the name-based parameters. If you want the operator to use that context object `ctx`, you *have* to pass it as first parameter. Having a copy of the context laying around in memory somewhere is not enough.

Comment: Worked for me exactly as posted.